# Moquette-Broker with BouncyCastle-TLS

Tags: java, mqtt, bouncycastle, moquette

I would like to know if there is a way to configure the Moquette-Broker to setup the TLS-Connection using the BouncyCastle-Library?
I need to implement the TLS-Connection-Setup with BouncyCastle because of the different configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

By default, moquette supports keystore and truststore configuration. If you really need to use BouncyCastle, I think that you should override the default implementation. Thi `NettyAcceptor.java` class can be helpful since it contains the pipeline definition. I think that `sslContext` created on your own just needs to be placed at first position in pipeline (something like `pipeline.addFirst(mySslContext)`.

https://github.com/andsel/moquette/blob/2fb475ae95989e7abc418dffbdd9104c818302bb/broker/src/main/java/io/moquette/server/netty/NettyAcceptor.java